# Where does C++20 prohibit sizeof...T (without parentheses)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++20, parameter-pack

Both g++ and clang++ reject the use of `sizeof...` when the argument is not parenthesized.  For example, the following code is rejected:

```
template<typename... T> auto packsize = sizeof...T;
```

```
$ g++  -std=c++20 -ggdb -O -Wall -Werror   -c -o z.o z.cc
z.cc:1:50: error: 'sizeof...' argument must be surrounded by parentheses [-fpermissive]
    1 | template<typename... T> auto packsize = sizeof...T;
      |                                                  ^
$ clang++  -std=c++20 -ggdb -O -Wall -Werror   -c -o z.o z.cc
z.cc:1:50: error: missing parentheses around the size of parameter pack 'T'
template<typename... T> auto packsize = sizeof...T;
                                                 ^
                                                 ()
1 error generated.
```

[CPPreference.org](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) also seems to require parentheses around `T`.  However, such a restriction does not appear in any of the obvious places in the C++20 standard, e.g., [the discussion of sizeof...](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.sizeof#4) or [the discussion of pack expansions](https://hsizettps://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.variadic#5.8).  However, all non-normative examples in the standard do include parentheses.

My question: what normative language prohibits the use of `sizeof...` with an unparenthesized identifier in C++20?

Comment: This is consistent with the non-... version, where `sizeof X` is valid when `X` is an object, but not when it's a type; with a type the parentheses are required, so `sizeof(X)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not really, you could have a non-type pack and would still need parentheses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's required by the grammar:

> **[`[expr.unary.general]/1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary#general-1)**
>
> *unary-expression*: 
>       ...
>       `sizeof` `...` `(` *identifier* `)`
>       ...